# laravel elequent filtering table with two input

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner in laravel, in my form, there is a table and some lookup fields like text input, which I want to search the values in and display on the table.
When I perform a search process on a text input like name, filtering the table after enter works fine، but when I add a number of search fields, like filtering on name and city, it no longer filters on any of the name or city fields. can't In fact, the request value in the controller returns an empty value.

Briefly,in indexfiltering.blade.php:

```
...
<div>
   <a href="{{ route('customers.indexfiltering')}}">search</a>
</div>
...
<div>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="{{ $name }}">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" value="{{ $city }}">
</div>
```

and in my controller:

```
public function indexFiltering(Request $request)
{
 $name= $request->query('name');
 $city= $request->query('city');
 if (!empty($name) || !empty($city)) {
    $customer= Customer::sortable()
   ->where('customer.name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')
   ->where('customer.city', $city)
   ->paginate(8);
 } else {
   $customers = customer::sortable()
   ->paginate(8);
 }

 return view('customers.indexfiltering',
 compact('customer'))
 ->with('customers', $customers)
 ->with('name', $name)
 ->with('city', $city);
 }
```

The second problem is that I want filtering to be done by selecting any item from the html select. Currently this is not done and selecting any option has no effect on filtering

Comment: if filtering using only by city ok? I mean did you try to leave the name empty and fill in the city and check what's happening? how do you keep the city in your database? Is it an ID or the name of the city? I'm asking this becuase you give a text as a city in your form.

Comment: city is text,The problem is that when I have only one search field such as name, the search is done by pressing enter, but when there are two search fields, the name field is no longer searched with enter.

Comment: Your lacking of conditions. So, should add more conditions. The logic should be like *name or city? name and city? !name? || !city?etc.*

Comment: It looks like I need to first solve the problem of why when I have two lookup fields no value is returned for $request

Answer (score 0):

You might need to start a query in the begining of the function like $query = Customer::query(); and check requests after.

```
$query = Customer::query();

if(request('name') && !empty(request('name'))) {
 $query->where('name', request('name'));
}
if(request('city') && !empty(request('city'))) {
 $query->where('city', request('city'));
}

$customers = $query->paginate(8); // or $query->get();

return $customers;
```

Comment: It looks like I need to first solve the problem of why when I have two lookup fields no value is returned for $request

Answer (score 0):

As my comment stated you are searching by name AND city always, never individually (due to your if statement).

You could change your code to below:

- It searches by `name` if name is not emtpy.
- It searches by `city` if city is not empty.
- And by both in case `name` and `city` are both not empty.

```
$name= $request->query('name');
$city= $request->query('city');

$query = Customer::query();

if (!empty($name) {
    $query->where('customer.name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%');
}

if (!empty($city) {
    $query->where('customer.city', $city)
}

$customers = $query->sortable()->paginate(8);

 return view('customers.indexfiltering', compact('customer'))
     ->with('customers', $customers)
     ->with('name', $name)
     ->with('city', $city);
 }
```

Comment: I modified my code like yours but The problem is that when I have only one search field such as name, the search is performed by pressing enter, but when the number of search fields becomes two, the name field is no longer searched with enter, and the page is not recalled at all.

Comment: It looks like I need to first solve the problem of why when I have two lookup fields no value is returned for $request

Comment: Depends on how you send you do the filtering I suppose. How do name and city end up in the query string?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the query to dynamically add conditions based on whether the input is set and not empty.

```
public function indexFiltering(Request $request)
{
    $query = Customer::query(); // Start the query builder chain

    // Check if the 'name' filter is set and not empty
    if ($request->has('name') && !empty($request->input('name'))) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('name') . '%');
    }

    // Check if the 'city' filter is set and not empty
    if ($request->has('city') && !empty($request->input('city'))) {
        $query->where('city', $request->input('city'));
    }

    // Paginate the results
    $customers = $query->sortable()->paginate(8);

    // Pass the filtered customers to the view
    return view('customers.indexfiltering', [
        'customers' => $customers,
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'city' => $request->input('city')
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a slightly cleaner option using the when() that allows to remove conditionals:

```
public function indexFiltering(Request $request)
{
    //validation

    $query = Customer::query(); 
      ->when(request('name'),
         fn($query) => $query->where('name', request('name'))//or like...
      )->when(request('city'),
         fn($query) => $query->where('city', request('city'))
      );

    // Paginate the results
    $customers = $query->sortable()->paginate(8);

    // Pass the filtered customers to the view
    return view('customers.indexfiltering', [
      'customers' => $customers,
      'name' => $request->input('name'),
      'city' => $request->input('city')
]);
}
```

Comment: It looks like I need to first solve the problem of why when I have two lookup fields no value is returned for $request

Comment: @mahdi.gh it looks like in your blade you don't have a form with the 2 inputs and a submit button, i would do that

Comment: Is it mandatory to have a submit button? Because I want the filter to be applied with the enter event

Comment: no you can do the way you prefer, but in that case you should add the code because that is where you probably have the issue (and you can inspect the payload (values of name and city) in dev tools)